# TableView not showing data from firebase but under "po snapshot" debug console shows the fetch data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
[The Table View is not showing any values that were defined in firebase.][1]
```

[Firebase is connected. When i do the Print object in the debug console, the defined data is being fetched]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZuKb.png

**Please feel free to organize and sort this out, im really new to this. 
    thanks
**
    //importing

> 

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class DatabaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //Firebase Refernece
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("CandleInventory").observe(.childAdded,  
with: { (snapshot) in
        //Execute Snapshot
        let candle = snapshot.value as! String?
        if let actualCandle = candle {
            self.candleData.append(actualCandle)

                    }
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

var candleData = [String]()


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return candleData.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, 
reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = candleData[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)
}


//Datajust wont output


}
```

Comment: reload on main thread. And don't put all that code inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: Please provide an example of how i can do this? i Tried putting the reload on the main thread but it still wont load

Comment: @Anfernee when you do print just above reload data, you can see the value getting printed?

Comment: Very probably `reloadData` must be inside the `observe` callback.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you want to reload data from the observer, that is, *after* the data has been appended:

```
databaseHandle = ref?.child("CandleInventory").observe(
   .childAdded,  
   with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
       guard let `self` = self else { return }

       let candle = snapshot.value as! String?
       guard let actualCandle = candle else { return }

       self.candleData.append(actualCandle)

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData() 
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: when inputing this, i get the error of "ambiguous use of "observer"" in the " databaseHandle = ref?.child..." line with the red under line on ".child"

Comment: @Anfernee I used traling closure but maybe that wouldn't work here so I have changed it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Few Points to remember**-:

1) Make sure `Data Source`  and `Delegate` are given to table view.

2) Performing some fetch request from **database or server**, make sure to
 reload table on main thread.

3) Make use of **reusable cell** in table, to save memory.

4) Never put code inside **viewDidLoad()**. Make separate functions and call them inside this function.

5) Make sure you have given correct table `cell identifier` as well.

6) Make sure you get `count` value in array.

7) Keep code **neat and clean**, for better understanding.

As you stated you can see values with print statement, also make sure they are appended in array, and  just reload table on main thread.

Code-:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class DatabaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 // OUTLETS AND VARIABLES

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
    var ref                      : FIRDatabaseReference!
    var databaseHandle           :FIRDatabaseHandle?

    var candleData               = [String]()


   //MARK-: viewDidLoad()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
  // CALL FUNCTION HERE
    fetchResultFromFirebase()
   }

  // didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   // FUNCTION TO CONNECT FIREBASE AND GET VALUES

    func fetchResultFromFirebase(){

   // FETCH DATA FROM FIREBASE

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("CandleInventory").observe(.childAdded, 
    with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
        //Execute Snapshot
        let candle = snapshot.value as! String?
        if let actualCandle = candle {

       // MAKE SURE VALUE IS APPENDED

        self.candleData.append(actualCandle) }
    })

   // RELOAD UI STUFF ON MAIN THREAD

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }

}

// TABLE VIEW numberOfRowsInSection

   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return candleData.count
   }

// ALWAYS USE REUSABLE CELLS

  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellComment", for: indexPath )

    cell.textLabel?.text = candleData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
 }

}
```

Comment: Adding a `MARK:` for every method an keeping empty implementations, e.g. for `didReceiveMemoryWarning` cannot be perceived as clean code. You also need to call `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks , corrected.I am in my learning stage as well, its good to learn from mistakes.

Comment: so this one says that "use of undeclared type "comment cell" "?

Comment: @Anfernee that's because you are not having any custom cell class. Or if you have one give that name, else remove that line ("comment cell").Also make sure to give correct identifier in storyboard and in code, else  app will crash.Edited code for what to be removed , if you don't have custom cell class.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple fix. I added some error handling for you and cleaned it up a bit if you don't mind. I don't know if you need to user `.observe` for your program but make sure you remove this listener eventually or use `observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded)` to only get it once. If this code doesn't produce anything on the first round then you may need to have a `.value` using a singleEvent and then this `.childAdded` using the `observer` event. Let me know if you need more assistance.

```
@objc func firebaseCall(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){
     ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("CandleInventory").observe(.childAdded,  
with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull{
            //Handle errors
            completionHandler(false)
            return
        }
        else{
            //Execute Snapshot
            if let candle = snapshot.value as? String{
                self.candleData.append(actualCandle)
                completionHandler(true)
            }
            else{
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        }
    })
}


override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
     firebaseCall() { result in
          if result{
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
          else{
              //No data found
          }
     }
}
```